# Are typescript project references necessary if transpiling with babel? (Electron project with Webpack)

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, electron, babeljs

I am still in the process of setting up my project configuration so I don't have any errors to work with right now, but if I am understanding the Typescript docs correctly...

It seems like Project references [TypeScript Docs - Project references](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/project-references.html) are not that necessary if transpiling with babel-loader in webpack. (I'm working in VSCode)

I am trying to convert an Electron app to TypeScript and currently reorganizing the folder structure so I have minimal issues.
I am trying to understand if I am on the right track and if I can avoid including "references" and instead just use "extends" to get the functionality I want.

Here is my project structure ignoring all files that are not tsconfig files:

```
./tsconfig.json
./tsconfig-base.json
./main/tsconfig.json
./src/client/tsconfig.json
./__tests__
./__tests__/__client__/tsconfig.json
./__tests__/__main__/tsconfig.json
```

In this structure `./tsconfig.json` would really just be for references like [the example on Microsoft's Github](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/tree/master/src)

Electron Main Process and related files are in `./main`. The tsconfig here will set `"module":"commonjs"` for working in node. I think it will also extend from the `./tsconfig-base.json`

Electron Renderer Process and my React-Redux app files are in `./src/client`. The tsconfig here sets `"module":"es2015"` or `"module":"ESNEXT"` for working with es modules. I think it will also extend from the `./tsconfig-base.json`

The `./__tests__/__client__/tsconfig.json` and `./__tests__/__main__/tsconfig.json` would just be duplicates of the non **tests** folder versions similarly extending from the base config in `./`

Webpack config is already set up to handle creating separate bundles for main and renderer processes so that the entire app can be in TypeScript. Is there any reason I should be using "references" in my files in the main or client folders?

Sample snippets of the Webpack config before I switch the tnry files to be .ts files (dev):

```
const rendererInclude = path.resolve(__dirname, "src");
const mainInclude = path.resolve(__dirname, "main");
```

Main Process:

```
module.exports = [
  {
    mode: "development",
    entry: path.join(__dirname, "main", "swell.js"),
    output: {
      path: path.join(__dirname, "dist"),
      filename: "main-bundle.js",
    },
    target: "electron-main",
    node: {
      __dirname: false,
      __filename: false,
    },
    resolve: {
      extensions: [".ts", ".tsx", ".js", ".json"],
    },
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.(ts|js)x?$/,
          loader: "babel-loader",
          include: mainInclude,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
        }
    ] } ... },
```

continued to Renderer Process:

```
{
    mode: "development",
    entry: path.join(__dirname, "src", "index.js"),
    output: {
      path: path.join(__dirname, "dist"),
      filename: "renderer-bundle.js",
    },
    target: "electron-renderer",
    resolve: {
      extensions: [".ts", ".tsx", ".js", ".json"],
    },
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.(ts|js)x?$/,
          loader: "babel-loader",
          include: rendererInclude,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
        ]} ...} ]
```

Answer (score 0):

**Project Reference** will help you solve some problems in case where your test projects import src/main modules.
This is what Project Reference solves:

- There’s no built-in up-to-date checking, so you end up always running tsc twice
- Invoking tsc twice incurs more startup time overhead
- tsc -w can’t run on multiple config files at once

read more about [Project References](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/project-references.html#an-example-project)